# reindex pandas MultiIndex on specific level

Tags: python, pandas

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_lowercase

tidx = pd.date_range(end='2016-04-30', freq='M', periods=3)
tidx2 = tidx + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(-1) + pd.offsets.Day(15) + pd.offsets.BDay(-1)

np.random.seed([3,1415])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(9, 1), columns=['Value'],
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([tidx, list(ascii_lowercase)[:3]]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(9, 1), columns=['Value'],
                   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([tidx2, list(ascii_lowercase)[:3]]))
```

I want to reindex `df2.index.levels[0]` with `df1.index.levels[0]`

What I've done:

```
 df1.unstack().reindex(df2.unstack().index, method='ffill').stack()
```

Looks like:

```
                 Value
2016-02-29 a  0.757983
           b  0.934829
           c  0.831104
2016-03-31 a  0.879891
           b  0.926879
           c  0.721535
2016-04-30 a  0.117642
           b  0.145906
           c  0.199844
```

However, this doesn't generalize to `MultiIndex`'s with more than 2 levels.

#### Question

What is a general way to `reindex` a specific level of an index?

Comment: I have edited my answer... again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: New solution, probably more in the spirit of the question:

```
def func(dfg):
    return dfg.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reindex(df1.index.levels[0], method='ffill')

df2.groupby(level=1).apply(func).swaplevel(i=0, j=1).sortlevel(0)
```

The idea is to group by the level 1 before reindexing as usual. Unlike the previous solution, this will perform a time-based forward fill.

**Second edit**: In order to generalize to multiple levels, replace `level=1` with:

```
level=list(range(1, df2.index.nlevels))
```

in both function calls.

---

**Previous answer**:

I don't know if this will work in all situations, but in this case it returns the result you want:

```
df2.index.set_levels(df1.index.get_level_values(0), level=0)
```

Result:

```
In [12]: df2
Out[12]: 
                 Value
2016-02-29 a  0.757983
           b  0.934829
           c  0.831104
2016-03-31 a  0.879891
           b  0.926879
           c  0.721535
2016-04-30 a  0.117642
           b  0.145906
           c  0.199844
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I generalized in this same way already.  I know I didn't post it.  I wanted to get people's fresh perspective.  This does answer the question and I will mark it as such unless there is a cleaner answer that shows up.  Thanks again for working on this.

Comment: Agreed, it's not elegant! Should I (temporarily) delete my answer to in order not to influence others. Besides, an upvoted question with no answer has a higher likelihood of attracting attention. Gamesmanship ;)